# Altering collation on field causes UNIQUE constraint to fail

Tags: mysql

When trying to alter my table with:

```
ALTER TABLE segment_item
CHANGE value value VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL;
```

I'm running into a UNIQUE constraint violation:

```
MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry for key 'segment_id'
```

Why would this be? This alteration to the table isn't adding a new record, it's just changing the character set and collation of existing records. For full visibility, here's the structure of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `segment_item` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `segment_id` binary(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_order` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `segment_id` (`segment_id`,`value`),
  KEY `value` (`value`),
  CONSTRAINT `segment_item_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`segment_id`) REFERENCES `segment` (`segment_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=36484 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_bin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The collation is how the db engine determines when records are unique. Looks like here you're changing from a binary collation (literally unique if and only if the bytes of the string are unique) to case insensitive unicode (which is case insensitive, but also uses a list of standard transformations to normalize digraphs, code point orders, etc).

So, for example, the following two strings used to be unique before your change (é is valid Latin-1):

```
Beyoncé
beyonce
```

But after the change they would be considered identical. My guess is that you have at least two "value"... er... values that are no longer unique under the new collation.